# Anyway to set the Docker image entrypoint when building the image or some equvalent?

Tags: docker, build, entry-point

I have a Dockerfile that I use to build the same image but for slightly different purposes. Most of the time I want it to just be an "environment" without a specific entrypoint so that the user just specifies that on the Docker run line:

```
docker run --rm -it --name ${CONTAINER} ${IMAGE} any_command parameters
```

But for some applications I want users to download the container and run it without having to set a command.

```
docker build -t ${IMAGE}:demo (--entrypoint ./demo.sh) <== would be nice to have
```

Yes, I can have a different Dockerfile for that, or append an entrypoint to the basic Dockerfile during builds, or various other mickey-mouse hacks, but those are all just one more thing that can go wrong, adding complexity, and are workarounds for the essential requirement.

Any ideas? staged builds?

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) directive sets the default command.  So if your Dockerfile ends with

```sh
CMD default_command
```

then you can run the image in multiple ways

```sh
docker run "$IMAGE"
# runs default_command

docker run "$IMAGE" any_command parameters
# runs any_command instead
```

A container *must* run a command; you can't "just run a container" with no process in it.

You do not want `ENTRYPOINT` here since its syntax is noticeably harder to work with at the command line.  Your `any_command` would be passed as arguments to the entrypoint process, rather than replacing the built-in default.